# Getting data for foreach loop in smarty

Tags: php, sql, foreach, smarty

I am trying to use smarty for a new website but I have a little problem assign data from a sql query to a smartyt foreach loop. I do not get any data from the query to my template.

In my class.designs.php I have this:

```
    function listAllDesigns() {
            global $db;

            $row = $db->query("
SELECT ds.*, count(com.comment) AS countcom 
FROM designs ds LEFT JOIN comments com ON com.design_id = ds.id 
WHERE ds.approved = 1 
GROUP BY ds.id 
ORDER BY ds.date_added ASC")->resultset();        

            $smarty = new Smarty;        
            $smarty->assign('designs', $row);

            return;        
        }
```

and my index.php

```
include_once("includes/connect.php"); //Database connection
include_once("includes/config.php"); //Configuration file
include_once("includes/classes/class.designs.php"); //Main design class

require('smarty/libs/Smarty.class.php');

$designs = new Designs();
$designs->listAllDesigns();

$smarty = new Smarty;
$smarty->debugging = true;
$smarty->caching = true;
$smarty->cache_lifetime = 120;

$smarty->assign("charset", $config->charset);
$smarty->assign("pagetitle", $config->pagetitle);
$smarty->display('index.tpl');
```

and in index.tpl I have this:

```
{foreach $designs as $r}
  <li>{$r.name}</li>
{foreachelse}
   No results 
{/foreach}
```

It just print "No result" and I am getting a "Undefined index designs" error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
include_once("includes/connect.php"); //Database connection
include_once("includes/config.php"); //Configuration file
include_once("includes/classes/class.designs.php"); //Main design class

require('smarty/libs/Smarty.class.php');

$designs = new Designs();
$designs->listAllDesigns();

$smarty = new Smarty;
$smarty->debugging = true;
$smarty->caching = true;
$smarty->cache_lifetime = 120;

// TO USE some value ($designs in your case) at your template you must assign it
// 1st is its name and 2nd is the value
$smarty->assign("designs", $designs);

$smarty->assign("charset", $config->charset);
$smarty->assign("pagetitle", $config->pagetitle);
$smarty->display('index.tpl');
```

Comment: Hmm.. that didn't seem to make any difference. I am still getting no results. If I var_dump($row) inside class.designs.php I can see the full array from the database - so I know I am getting data.

Comment: Arh .. made it work by setting _return $row;_ in the listAllDesigns function and then implementing your solution. That did it! 
Thank you!